# How do dimensions work in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm completely new to Python and Tensorflow. I want to implement a simple kind of CNN, and this is what I have done till now:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from libs import utils
import cv2
import glob

from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import reset_default_graph
reset_default_graph()

# We first get the graph that we used to compute the network
g = tf.get_default_graph()

# And can inspect everything inside of it
[op.name for op in g.get_operations()]



X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,720000])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

X_data = []
files = glob.glob ("C:/Users/Maede/Desktop/Master Thesis/imlearning/*.jpg")

for myFile in files:
    print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    X_data.append (image)

print('X_data shape:', np.array(X_data).shape)

data=np.array(X_data)
data=np.reshape(data,(30,720000))
label=np.array([(0,1),(1,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,1),(1,0),
               (0,1),(1,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,1),(1,0),
               (0,1),(1,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,1),(1,0)])

###########################################################
train_batch_size = 2
def random_batch():
    num_images = 30
    idx = np.random.choice(num_images,
                           size=train_batch_size,
                           replace=False)
    x_batch = data[idx,:]
    y_batch = label[idx, :]

    return x_batch, y_batch
######################
#

X_tensor = tf.reshape(X, [-1, 400,600,3])

filter_size = 5
n_filters_in = 3
n_filters_out = 32
W_1 = tf.get_variable(
    name='W',
    shape=[filter_size, filter_size, n_filters_in, n_filters_out],
    initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

b_1 = tf.get_variable(
    name='b',
    shape=[n_filters_out],
    initializer=tf.constant_initializer())

h_1 = tf.nn.relu(
    tf.nn.bias_add(
        tf.nn.conv2d(input=X_tensor,
                     filter=W_1,
                     strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                     padding='SAME'),
        b_1))

n_filters_in = 32
n_filters_out = 64
n_output = 2
W_2 = tf.get_variable(
    name='W2',
    shape=[filter_size, filter_size, n_filters_in, n_filters_out],
    initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
b_2 = tf.get_variable(
    name='b2',
    shape=[n_filters_out],
    initializer=tf.constant_initializer())
h_2 = tf.nn.relu(
    tf.nn.bias_add(
        tf.nn.conv2d(input=h_1,
                 filter=W_2,
                 strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                 padding='SAME'),
        b_2))

# We'll now reshape so we can connect to a fully-connected/linear layer:
h_2_flat = tf.reshape(h_2, [-1, 100*150* n_filters_out])

# NOTE: This uses a slightly different version of the linear function than the lecture!
h_3, W = utils.linear(h_2_flat, 400, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc_1')

# NOTE: This uses a slightly different version of the linear function than the lecture!
Y_pred, W = utils.linear(h_3, n_output, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name='fc_2')
y_one_hot = tf.one_hot( Y , 2 )


cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_one_hot  * tf.log(Y_pred + 1e-12))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y_pred, 1), tf.argmax(y_one_hot, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, 'float'))

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

batch_size = 2
n_epochs = 5
for epoch_i in range(n_epochs):
    for batch_xs, batch_ys in random_batch():
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={
                X: np.array(batch_xs).reshape([1,720000]),
                Y: batch_ys
        })
    valid = data   #### DATA haie validation
    print(sess.run(accuracy,
                   feed_dict={
                       X: data,
                       Y: label
                   }))
```

The input is 30 image with 400*600*3 dimension and i want to classify them into two class. The problem is when i'm using this command:
  `X: np.array(batch_xs).reshape([1,720000]),` 
The error is like below:
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (1,720000)

and when I'm using:

`X: batch_xs`

The error is:

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (720000,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 720000)'

I'm totally confused what is batch_xs dimension and why does it change in different situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.array(batch_xs)` is not the same size as your image.

`for batch_xs, batch_ys in random_batch()` is also a slightly strange way to run the code and I guess this also causes your problem. You usually use `for` to iterate over a some iterable.

In your case the iterable is just what your function returns, a tuple with `batch_xs, batch_ys`. But in the same step you are `unpacking` the first (!) value of the tuple into two variables `batch_xs` and `batch_ys`.

The `replace=False` does not do anything in your case, because you are calling the function `random_batch()` only once. In the next iteration it will have the complete dataset again.

Here is an simple example on your case:

```
import numpy as np

# I removed a dimension from the arrays
data = np.array([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                 [2.0, 2.0, 2.0],
                 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0]])

label = np.array([[10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
                   [20.0, 20.0, 20.0],
                   [30.0, 30.0, 30.0]])


def random_batch():

    idx = np.random.choice(3, size=2)
    x_batch = data[idx,:]
    y_batch = label[idx, :]

    return x_batch, y_batch


# the outer variable names x_batch and y_batch are not related at all to the ones
# inside random_batch()
# iterate over whatever random_batch() returns

# for x_batch, y_batch in random_batch() is equivalent to
# for (x_batch, y_batch) in random_batch()

# in the first iteration the iterable is `x_batch`, in the second one`y_batch`.
# and each of the iterable is "unpacked", basically in the first iteration 
# your are assigning

# (x_batch, y_batch) = x_batch

# in the second iteration 

# (x_batch, y_batch) = y_batch

# When unpacking you are splitting the two elements created by `size=2`
# in `random_batch()`

for (x_batch, y_batch) in random_batch():

    print(x_batch)
    print(y_batch)
```

This is fundamental Python basics, to get familiar with it look for `tuple unpacking`, `iterable` and `for loops`.

Replace the inner for-loop with this, it should work. It might not be what you expected, but it is what you code is supposed to do.

```
batch_xs, batch_ys = random_batch()
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={
      X: np.array(batch_xs).reshape([1,720000]),
            Y: batch_ys
      })
```

If if you want to train with 100 batches do something like this

```
for k in range(100):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = random_batch()
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={
          X: np.array(batch_xs).reshape([1,720000]),
                Y: batch_ys
          })
```

Usually you try to remove as much of the code that is not related to the problem to make it easier to find the problem. Find as less code as possible that still shows your problem.
Your problem is not related to tensorflow, so you could remove everything related to tensorflow to make it easier to find. Your problem is related to numpy and array shapes.

Comment: Actually its not my real data since they arent available yet. but i want to construct my classifier with few fake data.
i put train_batch_size=2 to pick two image for training and 'for' loop is for this purpose
your suggested commands couldnt help me. the first one: `np.array(batch_xs).reshape([train_batch_size, 720000])`
has this error: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 720000 into shape (2,720000)
and the second one makes it 1440000 which again couldnt be feed in placeholder X with [None,720000] dimension

Comment: I think i need this `for` loop to repeat optimization for both batch images. ( i choose batch_size to be 2)
yes i want to train my network with some random images

Comment: Did you add the line `print('shape', batch_xs.shape)` right before `sess.run(...)`? This should outout the shape of the current batch. Try thant and tell me the shape.

Comment: I added an example and some text at the end of my answer. Please try that

Comment: yes, i understand. I should minimize my code as possible to show my problem. Thank you for your suggestion.
I tried `print('shape', batch_xs.shape)`, its (2, 720000).
actually i want to pick two random images with size of (400*600*3=720000) in each epoch and train my network.
In your suggested code, since `for` loop is eliminated, the dimension error is changed to: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1440000 into shape (1,720000) 
because its trying to feed two image (720000*2=1440000) to `y` as placeholder which is [None 720000] dimension.

Comment: how can i implement `for` loop in this problem to feed each of the random images to my X and Y placeholders?

Comment: I adjusted my answer.

Comment: My problem Solved by your answers and help! Thank you very much.